# How do I fix mouse freezing when sound playback is active on Debian?

Tags: linux, usb, debian, mouse

I'm having a fairly frustrating problem with my Debian machine. The problem is that the pointer of my USB mouse freezes shortly after I start playing sound through the headphones, which are also USB.

In more details: I'm running a current kernel

```
3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My mouse is a standard Microsoft USB mouse. My headphones are Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000. Here's a `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 045b:0210 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045b:0210 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 045e:070f Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 045e:077d Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045b:0209 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045b:0209 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Bus 3, device 4 is the mouse, device 5 are the headphones. There's also an integrated Intel sound card, output of `arecord -l`:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC898 Analog [ALC898 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC898 Digital [ALC898 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC898 Alt Analog [ALC898 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 2/2
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
card 2: LX3000 [Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Life is great until I start playing sound through the headphones. The sound works but the mouse pointer freezes after some time - sometimes almost immediately, sometimes after several seconds, but never very long. Re-plugging the mouse makes it work again, and I've been trying to use the [USB reset code from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line), which also works - resetting `/dev/bus/usb/003/004` brings the mouse back to life, until it freezes again in a few seconds. Unless, of course, I stop playing sound, in which case it's fine.

I've tried disabling the `autosuspend` option of the `usbcore` module with no result. When the mouse freezes, there's no message added to `dmesg` output, so at this point I feel I'm out of good ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug the issue deeper. First, it sounds like the verbosity of your debug log can be higher, if you don't get any messages related to HID hang-up.

Second, try to "regress" the issue. Try to use a USB 2.0 hub between your "Debian machine" and your audio and mouse devices. Try different tree configurations, say, the mouse is connected to the root port, but headphones are behind the hub. Or vice versa. Or both devices are behind the hub.

Try different devices, like a FS-type wireless Logitech mouse instead of LS-wired mouse. Or a different brand of headphones (typically a FS device). What kind of machine are you using? What type/version of USB controller does it have?

It is also useful to determine if the USB ports employ any power management on the links. This should be visible from the logs (there should be WAKEUP and RESUME messages, and corresponding interrupts). A trace from an USB protocol analyzer would be nice to have on the failing link.